# A strange integral having to do with the sophomore's dream:

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, closed-form

I recently noticed that this really weird equation actually carries a closed form!

$$\int_0^1 \left(\frac{x^x}{(1-x)^{1-x}}-\frac{(1-x)^{1-x}}{x^x}\right)\text{d}x=0$$

I honestly do not know how to prove this amazing result! I do not know nearly enough about the sophomore's dream integral properties to answer this question, which I have been trying to apply here. (If possible, please stay with real methods, as I do not know contour integration yet)

Answer (score 100, accepted):

It is important to note some symmetry:

Consider: $$I=\int_0^1 \frac{x^x}{(1-x)^{1-x}}\text{d}x$$

If you substitute $x\to 1-x, \text{d}x\to -\text{d}x$

You are left with:

$$I=-\int_{1-0}^{1-1}\frac{(1-x)^{(1-x)}}{(1-(1-x))^{(1-(1-x))}}\text{d}x=\int_0^1 \frac{(1-x)^{1-x}}{x^x}\text{d}x$$

And your integral is only $I-I=0$, your result. You didn't even need to know $x^x$ properties!

In fact, this can be further generalized:

$$\int_0^1 \frac{f(x)}{f(1-x)}\text{d}x=\int_0^1 \frac{f(1-x)}{f(x)}\text{d}x$$

Comment: I did not expect such a positive reaction from this answer! Thank you all!

Comment: You can actually take this even further: $\int_0^n f(x)\text{d}x=\int_0^n f(n-x)\text{d}x$!

Comment: I didn't know that, but it makes sense! @Pockets

Comment: It's actually rather surprising that you didn't notice what Pocket pointed out haha.. It's just area under the curve reflected across a line of symmetry.

Comment: @Arbitrary, if you think about it, taking $g(x) = \frac{f(x)}{f(1-x)}$ gives the left side to be $\int_0^1 g(x)\text{d}x$, and the right side to be $\int_0^1 g(1-x)\text{d}x$, and if you spend a little time thinking about why that's the case, you'll notice that you can just replace the 1 with $n$, because reflecting the graph of $g(x)$ across $x=\frac{n}{2}$ gives you $g(n-x)$. Or, in other words, where $x+y=2n$, you actually have $\int_x^y f(x)\text{d}x=\int_x^y f(n-x)\text{d}x$!

Comment: @Pockets, "!" in front of a number causes an ambiguity in mathematics :))

Comment: I believe that you guys are misinterpreting what I am getting at. When I did my proof, I just didn't see it. However, now that you show it to me, it does make sense :)

Comment: +1, but it should be noted that this only proves that *if* the integral exists, *then* it must be zero.

Comment: @ruakh Yes, good point. However, when I posted that comment, I thought that was assumed.

Comment: @Arbitrary I would like to award a bounty manually on this answer. I think that it deserves more credit than it currently has.

Comment: @user0 Well, I won't say no... I really don't care about rep, though

Comment: I'm not trying to be pushy, but I am soo... close to a gold badge.

Answer (score 14):

So you have an integral:
$$I = \int_0^1 \left(\frac{x^x}{(1-x)^{1-x}}-\frac{(1-x)^{1-x}}{x^x}\right)\text{d}x$$

Let's split the area of integration by half:

$$I =
\int_0^{\tfrac 12} \left(\frac{x^x}{(1-x)^{1-x}}-\frac{(1-x)^{1-x}}{x^x}\right)\text{d}x
+
\int_{\tfrac 12}^1 \left(\frac{x^x}{(1-x)^{1-x}}-\frac{(1-x)^{1-x}}{x^x}\right)\text{d}x
$$

and substitute $y=1-x$ in the second term:

$$I =
\int_0^{\tfrac 12} \left(\frac{x^x}{(1-x)^{1-x}}-\frac{(1-x)^{1-x}}{x^x}\right)\text{d}x
+
\int_{\tfrac 12}^0 \left(\frac{(1-y)^{1-y}}{y^y}-\frac{y^y}{(1-y)^{1-y}}\right)(-\text{d}y)
$$
$$
=\int_0^{\tfrac 12} \left(\frac{x^x}{(1-x)^{1-x}}-\frac{(1-x)^{1-x}}{x^x}\right)\text{d}x
+
\int_{\tfrac 12}^0 \left(\frac{y^y}{(1-y)^{1-y}}-\frac{(1-y)^{1-y}}{y^y}\right)\text{d}y
$$

Now we swap the limits of integration for $y$:
$$I =
\int_0^{\tfrac 12} \left(\frac{x^x}{(1-x)^{1-x}}-\frac{(1-x)^{1-x}}{x^x}\right)\text{d}x
-
\int_0^{\tfrac 12} \left(\frac{y^y}{(1-y)^{1-y}}-\frac{(1-y)^{1-y}}{y^y}\right)\text{d}y
$$
and after a few minutes of staring up we see the expression is
$$I = K - K$$
with
$$K = \int_0^{\tfrac 12} \left(\frac{x^x}{(1-x)^{1-x}}-\frac{(1-x)^{1-x}}{x^x}\right)\text{d}x$$

Hence $I = 0$.

Answer (score 3):

As *property of definite integrals*   it is known that for any function *integrand $f(x)$*

$$\int_0^a{f(x)}\text{d}x = \int_0^a{f(a-x)}\text{d}x$$

Geometrically this means the area under the curve when flipped about the line $ x= \dfrac{a}{2}$ as a rigid figure cannot change. The property can be stated symbolically as in  one particular generalisation where ${p} $ is a constant:

$$\int_0^1 \frac{f(x)^p}{f(1-x)^p}\text{d}x=\int_0^1 \frac{f(1-x)^p}{f(x)^p}\text{d}x.$$

For *p = 1* you can write the integrand  also as a product in another  example.

$$ \int_0^{\pi}{\cos^5 \phi \sin \phi }\, d \phi = \int_0^{\pi}{\sin ^5 \phi \cos \phi }\, d \phi $$

I am sure the generalisation  takes a fanciful attention.Earlier days I would imagine a "curved roof trapezoid " and flip it without change of area under the roof.